# Is there a way to plot the derivative of an implicit function in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

After having read the manuals and searched extensively, I could not find a way to do the following.

Suppose you have an implicit equation of the form

$y^4 + y^5 = x$, and $y$ is a function of $x$.

Now, using `ContourPlot`, one can easily graph y against x. However, I would like to know if there is a method to graph `y'` against `x` (i.e. $dy/dx$ against `x`). I haven't come across any such thing yet.

Comment: You can get the solution with something like `sol[x_] = y /. Solve[y^4 + y^5 == x, y]` and `solp[x_] = D[#, x] & /@ sol[x]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you wanted something like this:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[
                     Eliminate[{y^4 + y^5 - x == 0, Dt[y^4 + y^5 - x == 0, x]} /.
                               Dt[y, x] :> yp, y]],
            {x, -7, 7}, {yp, -7, 7}, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image: implicit function's derivative]

The key here is the use of `Dt[]` to differentiate the implicit Cartesian equation, and `Eliminate[]` to eliminate `y`; in this case, we have an algebraic equation and `Eliminate[]` had no difficulty, but this technique will be less successful once transcendental functions are involved.

Comment: Well, this is not plotting anything for me!

Comment: Really? Did you copy the code into *Mathematica*? What version/OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro, Mathematica 9. i copied the exact code.

Comment: Very peculiar. No error messages whatsoever?

Comment: Nothing. It just does nothing.

Comment: Can you maybe take a screenshot of what you're seeing, and post a link to it?

Comment: http://sdrv.ms/1532S12

Comment: You didn't copy the code, you typed it in yourself. I can tell because I see you used `Set[]` (`=`) instead of `Equal[]` (`==`) as in my answer.

Comment: Well no I copied it exactly. Thats because of the output format of Mathematica which parses the == and shows it as an =

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what's happening in version 9. I did this in version 8.

Comment: Well now that you mention it, I typed it and got the graph! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One easy way would be to use the ParametricPlot. Indeed, since y'(x)=1/x'(y) and

```
 x[y_] := y^4 + y^5;
```

one finds that y' is expressed as

```
 1/D[x[y], y]
```

yielding

```
1/(4 y^3 + 5 y^4)
```

Than one can plot as follows. Evaluate it:

```
    ParametricPlot[{y^4 + y^5, 1/(4 y^3 + 5 y^4)}, {y, 0.3, 1.2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y'"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can take the `ContourPlot` of the equation and replace all the y coordinates with the value of the derivative.  This will be a fast transformation of the `ContourPlot`, but the main drawback is that the adaptive plotting algorithms are applied to the original equation, not to the derivative.  Rapid changes in the derivative and exclusions will not be handled automatically.

The basic idea can be achieved like this.

```
f = y^4 + y^5 - x;
dydx[f_] := dydx[f] = -D[f, x]/D[f, y] /. {x -> #1, y -> #2} &;
pl = ContourPlot[f == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
pl /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest___] :> GraphicsComplex[{#1, dydx[f][##]} & @@@ pts, rest]
```

[image: plot of dy/dx]

One might also wish to automate this.  One problem above is that it might happen that `D[f, y]` is zero.  One might catch this and give back a very large derivative.  There is an option `showFunction` to plot the original equation along with the derivative and another `derivativeStyle` to set the style of the `dy/dx` plot.  (Note: The syntax coloring complains of a scope conflict in the definition of `dfplot`; changing `Block[..]` to `Block @@ Hold[..]` makes the annoying coloring go away.  Both ways seem to work.)

```
ClearAll[dydx, dfplot];

dydx[f_, x_, y_] := With[{dfx = D[f, x], dfy = D[f, y]}, 
   dydx[f, x, y] = If[(dfy /. {x -> #1, y -> #2}) == 0,
      $MaxMachineNumber, -dfx/dfy /. {x -> #1, y -> #2}] &];

SetAttributes[dfplot, HoldAll];
Options[dfplot] = {showFunction -> False, 
    derivativeStyle -> Directive[ColorData[1][2]]} ~Join~ Options[ContourPlot];
dfplot[eqn_, domain1 : {x_, __}, domain2 : {y_, __}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{x, y},
  With[{f = eqn[[1]] - eqn[[2]],
        plot = ContourPlot[eqn, domain1, domain2, 
          Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ContourPlot]]]},
   Show[
    If[OptionValue[showFunction], plot, {}],
    plot /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, prim_, rest___] :> 
      GraphicsComplex[{#1, dydx[f, x, y][##]} & @@@ pts, 
       prim /. Tooltip[e_, label_] :> Tooltip[e, -D[f, x]/D[f, y]] /. 
         l_Line :> {OptionValue[derivativeStyle], l}, rest]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

The OP's example:

```
dfplot[y^4 + y^5 == x, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, showFunction -> True]
```

[image: Plot output]

Another example for which J.M.'s eliminate method took too long:

```
dfplot[x^2 y - x^3 y^3 + 3 y^4 == 3, {x, -5, 7}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 showFunction -> True, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Plot output]

Comment: For sufficiently complicated algebraic functions, I'd probably replace `Eliminate[]` with `GroebnerBasis[]`: `GroebnerBasis[{x^2 y - x^3 y^3 + 3 y^4 == 3, Dt[x^2 y - x^3 y^3 + 3 y^4 == 3, x] /. Dt[y, x] -> yp}, {x, yp}, y, MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]`